# Several independent exponential decay processes

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a bag containing tiles, each tile with a letter of the alphabet written on it (each letter appears once). I draw repeatedly one tile at a constant rate, and replace any letter tile with a blank tile. I understand that this is an exponential decay process, and that I can calculate the number of letter tiles $N(t)$ at time $t$ with the formula $N(t) = N_0 e^{-\lambda t}$, where $N_0$ is the original quantity and $\lambda$ is the replacement rate.

My question is about a more complex case: I now have two bags instead of one, and each time I draw and replace a tile as described above in parallel from both bags. I would like to know how many *common* letter tiles I can expect to find in bag 1 and 2 at time $t$. Then, how can I generalize this to any number of $n$ bags?